# Adding page querystring to WebGrid headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I am using a WebGrid and it sorts and pages but if I am on page 3 for instance and click on a column header to sort by that particular column then I only get sort and sortdir query string parameters and lose my page parameter.  This means that I end up on page 1.  How do I fix this?

Thanks,

sachin

Comment: I'm surprised no one has come across this before.  I would have thought everyone who has worked with WebGrid would have had this issue.

Comment: There is a PageIndex property.

Comment: I don't quite see how that will help.

Comment: Why wouldn't you go to the first page? The two first pages have changed when you sorted. There is no logical reason to stay on page three.